# NodeJS module structure for multiple .js files with functions

Tags: node.js

ATM I have a folder in my NodeJS application where I store my JS files with a couple of functions. I require these files in my main.js at the top an use them as usual.

```
my-app/
├── node_modules/
├── my_jsfiles/
│   ├── functions_1.js
│   └── functions_2.js
├── package.json
└── main.js
```

main.js:

```
const myFuncs1 = require('./my_jsfiles/functions_1.js')
const myFuncs2 = require('./my_jsfiles/functions_2.js')

myFuncs1.someFuncsInside()
myFuncs2.someFuncsInside()
```

APPROACH: Now that I am going to use my_jsfiles in more applications I would like to make my own NodeJS module, which works so far, but I stuck at the point how I can include multiple js files instead of just calling functions from the index.js

```
my-app/
├── node_modules/
│   ├── my-jsfunctions/
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── functions_1.js
│   │   └── functions_2.js
├── package.json
└── main.js
```

main.js:

```
const myFuncs = require('my-jsfunctions')
//How do I call functions from functions_1.js and functions_2.js?
```

I know that I can export functions from the index.js

```
exports.someFunction = function () {
    console.log("This is a message from the index.js");
}
```

But what is the propper way to call functions from the other files, because I do not want to have just one index.js file with million lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to import all your functions into index.js file and export from there

```
my-app/
├── node_modules/
├── my_jsfiles/
│   ├── functions_1.js
│   └── functions_2.js
├── package.json
└── main.js
```

**function_1.js**

```
function functions_1_1(){
}
module.exports={functions_1_1}
```

**function_2.js**

```
function functions_2_1(){
}
module.exports={functions_2_1}
```

**index.js**

```
const {functions_1_1} = require("./function_1.js");
const {functions_2_1} = require("./function_2.js");
module.exports={functions_1_1,functions_2_1}
```

**main.js**

```
const {functions_1_1,functions_2_1} =require("./my_jsfiles/index.js");
functions_1_1()
functions_2_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to do

```
const myFuncs1 = require('my_jsfiles/functions_1.js')
const myFuncs2 = require('my_jsfiles/functions_2.js')
```

isn't it working?

Comment: That should work. I thought there is maybe a better way wo include just the module and the myFuncs.myFuncs1.someFuncs and myFuncs.myFuncs2.someFuncs.

Answer (score 1):

From your file index.js on my-jsfunctions, you can export function from other files like so

```
export * from './functions_1';
export * from './functions_2';
```

then you can import function

```
const func1 = require('my-jsfunctions').func1;
const func2 = require('my-jsfunctions').func2;
```